# Please check if there's anything wrong with my 555 PWM schematic

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, pwm, schematics, 555

[image: NE555 PWM schematics]

My first time creating an EAGLE CAD schematic. I want to turn this into a PCB.

I want to ask if there's anything wrong with my schematic, like the wiring or the efficiency or something like that.

Comment: So are you worried about (a) the connections being correct in the schematics regardless of the quality of schematics, or (b) the quality and readability of the schematics regardless of connections being correct, or (c) both. My feedback is that it is hard to check if connections are correct because the connections and components are drawn in quite random fashion.

Comment: The circuit is what it is because, without some statement from you what your functional and performance expectations are, it's gonna do what it's gonna do and who is to say whether this is right or wrong. You may have intentionally drawn the schematic in a fairly haphazard way intentionally also.

Comment: The polarity of the LED is backwards.

Answer (score 4):

R2 is doing nothing but wasting power. Depending on the value of C2, 1N400x diodes may not work as well as faster diodes.

There is a ground missing between the IRF510 source and 555 ground.

No voltages are shown so it is unclear whether there is sufficient drive for the MOSFET (12V supply would be enough) or if there is too much voltage to be safe.

It’s unclear where the load is to be connected or what it is, the MOSFET specified is pretty high Rds(on). The LED is backwards.

There may be other issues, but those stand out to me. Perhaps you should tell us exactly the intended purpose of the circuit, the supply voltage(s), the exact nature of the load and how you intend to connect it.

Comment: The lack of decoupling capacitor on the supply voltage, albeit possibly tolerable in low-speed usage, would also stand out, because it's just such an "automatic" thing you do. You see an IC, it gets a 10 nF to 100 nF capacitor close to the supply voltage pin, unless you have any specific reason to doubt that's a good idea.

Comment: Yes, a bypass cap would be a good idea, maybe a bit higher value than usual (perhaps 10-100uF electrolytic parallel with 100nF) since the old bipolar 555 draws big spikes of current. A 10nF cap on the control voltage pin is also commonly used.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer Spehro Pefhany, i actually wanted to make a pwm for a diy vape and for highload/current. I haven't implemented this into a real circuit yet, i will try very soon, i will try to make a better schematic. THankyou for the answer i appreciate it and also Marcus Mu:ller